# What does 'by' in these two sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, sentence-choice

> 1)There were several street vendors selling snacks **by** the
> footpath.

> 2)Having warm tea **by** the tea cart ear my  university was my favorite pastime.

Comment: The vendors were _beside_ the footpath. The tea drinker could have been standing _at, near_ or _beside_, the cart. (I assume that _ear_ is a typo for _near_!)

Answer (score 2):

In both of these cases, it's a preposition meaning **near/close to**.

In 1, the street vendors are near the footpath.

In 2, the writer drank (had) their tea near the tea cart.